# Installshield 2010 fails when paths have unicode characters

Tags: unicode, installshield, unicode-string, installshield-2010

I'm using Installshield 2010 premier edition.

When I try to install our software with an installation package, Installshield always terminates abnormally. The reproduce sequence is following:

1. Set Windows(7 or 8) Locale to English
2. Install Korean Language Pack for Windows
3. Change Windows Locale from English to Korean
4. Create a Windows user account with Korean Characters
5. Login to Windows with the new user account
6. Change Windows Locale from Korean To English
7. Launch the installation
8. The installation is terminated abnormally

The installation worked just fine with the above sequence if I built the installation package with Installshield 2011. I found out the article on your Installshield release note that setup within unicode paths is only supported Installshield 2011 or after. (http://kb.flexerasoftware.com/selfservice/viewContent.do?externalId=Q208910)

Is there any work around to make Installshield 2010 support the setup within Unicode included paths?

Answer (score 0):

You didn't mention which kind of installation you're running (InstallScript or Windows Installer). For Windows Installer setups before we introduced proper Unicode support, sometimes you can get away with creating a single .msi file for installation. (Most of the difficulties related to non-codepage Unicode paths were within setup.exe, so bypassing it alleviates many of them.) If you're using an InstallScript installation, this isn't an option, as it requires the setup.exe launcher.

Comment: I'm using InstallScript installation. And I found out that SUPPORTDIR path, which is a non-codepage Unicode path, has unicode characters.

Comment: Then the answer is no; you'll need IS2011. The InstallScript engine was only upgraded to be Unicode internally as of IS2011. Before that it was ANSI (mostly for legacy reasons, including its Windows 9x support). So while for a long time you could interop with some limited Unicode (COM Objects, UseDLL, etc.), core functionality was ANSI.

Comment: Hmmmmm. Then I may need to buy a new version of IS. Thanks, Michael.